# SQL Join не дает нужного результата

Tags: php, yii2, mysqli, activerecord

Есть вот такой запрос -

```
$tasks = Tasks::find()
        ->where('STATUS_ID = 1')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'CITIES', 'TASKS.CITY_ID = CITIES.CITY')
        ->orderBy("PUBLICATION_DATE DESC")
        ->all();
```

Его SQL-запрос будет таким -

```
SELECT `TASKS`.* FROM `TASKS` LEFT JOIN `CITIES` ON TASKS.CITY_ID = CITIES.CITY WHERE STATUS_ID = 1 ORDER BY `PUBLICATION_DATE` DESC
```

Запрос ссылается на вторую таблицу CITIES, где внешним ключом есть связь с первой таблицей TASKS и соответственно к каждому задания я хочу видеть `название города`, а не его `идентификатор`. Результатом запроса является таблица, где в строке `CITY_ID` таблицы `TASKS` стоит число, а не название города. Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Схема создания обеих таблиц:

```
    CREATE TABLE TASKS 
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
PUBLICATION_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
TITLE TEXT NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL,
BUDGET INT,
FILES VARCHAR(255),
STATUS_ID INT,
EXECUTION_DATE DATETIME,
CATEGORY_ID INT NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
EXECUTIONER_ID INT,
CITY_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORIES(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (EXECUTIONER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CITY_ID) REFERENCES CITIES(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (STATUS_ID) REFERENCES STATUSES(ID)
);

    CREATE TABLE CITIES 
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
CITY TEXT,
LATITUDE DECIMAL(18, 7),
LONGDITUDE DECIMAL(18, 7) 
);
```

Результат по моему запросу

```
|_. ID |_. PUBLICATION_DATE |_. TITLE |_. DESCRIPTION |_. BUDGET |_. FILES |_. STATUS_ID |_. EXECUTION_DATE |_. CATEGORY_ID |_. CUSTOMER_ID |_. EXECUTIONER_ID |_. CITY_ID |
| 13 | 2023-07-01 11:38:30 | Doloribus. | Odio sit velit nihil. | 8087 |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |  | 592 |
| 6 | 2023-07-01 11:38:19 | Sit. | Eius et et ratione. | 2513 |  | 1 |  | 8 | 1 |  | 376 |
| 5 | 2023-07-01 11:38:17 | Magni. | Sint id assumenda aut. | 3667 |  | 1 |  | 8 | 1 |  | 210 |
```

UPD. Благодаря @InDevX смог сделать корректный JOIN и по итогу в SQL менеджере получаю таблицу с нужным названием города

```
 |_. ID |_. PUBLICATION_DATE |_. TITLE |_. DESCRIPTION |_. BUDGET |_. FILES |_. STATUS_ID |_. EXECUTION_DATE |_. CATEGORY_ID |_. CUSTOMER_ID |_. EXECUTIONER_ID |_. CITY_ID |_. TASK_CITY |
| 13 | 2023-07-01 11:38:30 | Doloribus. | Odio sit velit nihil. | 8087 |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |  | 592 | Мценск |
| 6 | 2023-07-01 11:38:19 | Sit. | Eius et et ratione. | 2513 |  | 1 |  | 8 | 1 |  | 376 | Карпинск |
| 5 | 2023-07-01 11:38:17 | Magni. | Sint id assumenda aut. | 3667 |  | 1 |  | 8 | 1 |  | 210 | Горняк |
```

Проблема теперь в том, что `var_dump` экземпляра модели не показывает созданный столбик, и в PHP я не могу к нему обратиться для вывода на страницу

```
object(app\models\Tasks)#86 (10) { ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(12) { ["ID"]=> int(13) ["PUBLICATION_DATE"]=> string(19) "2023-07-01 11:38:30" ["TITLE"]=> string(10) "Doloribus." ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(21) "Odio sit velit nihil." ["BUDGET"]=> int(8087) ["FILES"]=> NULL ["STATUS_ID"]=> int(1) ["EXECUTION_DATE"]=> NULL ["CATEGORY_ID"]=> int(1) ["CUSTOMER_ID"]=> int(1) ["EXECUTIONER_ID"]=> NULL ["CITY_ID"]=> int(592) } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(12) { ["ID"]=> int(13) ["PUBLICATION_DATE"]=> string(19) "2023-07-01 11:38:30" ["TITLE"]=> string(10) "Doloribus." ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(21) "Odio sit velit nihil." ["BUDGET"]=> int(8087) ["FILES"]=> NULL ["STATUS_ID"]=> int(1) ["EXECUTION_DATE"]=> NULL ["CATEGORY_ID"]=> int(1) ["CUSTOMER_ID"]=> int(1) ["EXECUTIONER_ID"]=> NULL ["CITY_ID"]=> int(592) } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: в запрос добавьте что-то типа `->select('TASKS.*, CITIES.CITY AS TASK_CITY')`  и в TASK_CITY будет название,

Comment: @InDevX добавил, теперь запрос возвращается таблицу со столбцом `TASK_CITY` в котором все значения равны `NULL`

Comment: Значит некорректный join... `TASKS.CITY_ID = CITIES.CITY` => `TASKS.CITY_ID = CITIES.ID`

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо, теперь в SQL менеджере получаю таблицу со столбцом `TASK_CITY` где есть название города. Проблема теперь в том, что такого атрибута в модели нет, соответственно в PHP я не могу к нему обратиться и вывести на страницу

Comment: Добавьте тег yii (yii2?) в вопрос, я с yii не дружу, подсказать не могу ничего

Comment: @InDevX понял, в любом случае спасибо Вам огромное за помощь! Мне для нового вопроса лучше создать новую тему или оставить обсуждение здесь?

Comment: Думаю, то что Вам надо - [Работа со связными данными](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-). Там всё написано, нужно добавить связи в модель и потом можно будет без join обойтись и всё будет в модели. Если с этим трудности возникнут то отдельный вопрос создавайте

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря @InDevX нашел решение своего вопроса. По итогу отказался от `join`, теперь запрос выглядит так -

```
$tasks = Tasks::find()
        ->where('STATUS_ID = 1')
        ->orderBy("PUBLICATION_DATE DESC")
        ->all();
```

В моделях уже были настроены связи `hasOne` и `hasMany`, поэтому в файле `index.php` запрос к необходимой информации по связи выглядит следующим образом

```
$task->cATEGORY->CATEGORY
```

Решение, как зачастую бывает, было на поверхности

Comment: Один важный нюанс: если $tasks в цикле перебираете то сколько вызываете $task->category - столько и запросов будет, это называется проблемой n +1 запроса. Чтобы избежать этого нужно "загружать" связи в основном запросе, банально добавить `->with('category')`